# Why would running a Rails app as a WEBrick server work, but installing it as a Mongrel service would not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, mongrel, webrick

Yet another newbie RoR question from me.

I started banging my head against a wall last night when I simply could *not* get my Rails app to display in my browser after installing it as a Mongrel service.

I installed it using a command like this (from the app's root directory):

```
mongrel_rails service::install -N MyAppName -e development -p 3000
```

This set up the Windows service and everything seemed to be just fine. I could start/stop the service and saw no errors in the logs. Then navigating to `localhost:3000` in my browser, I was greeted with a variety of errors, none Rails-specific (all along the lines of "Could not connect to server" or the like). Consulting the log at this point revealed no obvious problems.

I could not for the life of me figure out how to get this to work. So, out of exasperation, I tried simply running the app on WEBrick instead:

```
ruby script/server webrick -p 3000
```

When I did *this*, my app ran perfectly! Opening my browser to `localhost:3000` now displayed my front page as expected.

I should note that I have used Mongrel *successfully* for *other* apps on my local machine.

So what app-specific characteristics could be responsible for WEBrick working where Mongrel doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Just some ideas to try:

1. Add -c param with full path to application:
   `-c "C:\xxx\yyy\zzz"`
2. Check if system-wide PATH environment variable contains ruby bin directory - maybe just user's PATH is set.
3. Switch service to run as your user.